# Meteor 0.9.1.1: how to use a spinner

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm looking at using this [spinner](https://github.com/bitIO/meteor-loading) so when something is submitted to the backend I can show the spinner to the client while the backend is doing its thing.

I just want to know if I've got the correct idea about this.

I call a function "myfunction" from the client to the backend:

```
var result = Meteor.call('myfunction', {});
//start spinner
createNewSpinner (selector, spinnerOpts);
createLoadingOverlay (target, overlayColor)

if(result == true) {
  //stop spinner
  destroyLoadingOverlay (selector);
}


// backend function
Meteor.methods({
  myfunction: function(data) {
  // logic here
  return true;
  }
});
```

I'm really not sure about my pseudo code, there's not any examples in the documentation of how to use the spinner.  Looks like it might be invoked differently than how spin.js is so any pointers/code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete working example:

```html
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Spinner Demo</h1>
  <button>Start</button>
  <div id='overlay'></div>
</template>
```

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function() {
      // options for the spinner and target selector
      var color = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)';
      var options = {lines: 10, length: 20, speed: 1};
      var selector = '#overlay';

      // add the overlay
      LoadingOverlay.createLoadingOverlay(selector, color);
      // remove the default spinner
      $('.spinner').remove();
      // add our custom spinner
      LoadingOverlay.createNewSpinner('loading', options);

      Meteor.call('myfunction', {}, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
          // remove the overlay on success
          LoadingOverlay.destroyLoadingOverlay(selector);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {  
  Meteor.methods({
    myfunction: function(data) {
      // simulate a delay
      Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

The key is to remove the overlay in the callback (after the asynchronous method has completed).